# How to use the milestones field | send_client_offer | ODesk API Python Library

Tags: python, odesk

The oDesk API does not give a concrete example for how to use the milestones parameter for the send_client_offer function. I've tried using a python dictionary, but receive an error when I do so.

The documentation describes milestones as an array:

```
milestones[0][$key]`, ..., `milestones[N][$key]
```

But it's unclear how that should be implemented in the python library:

I've tried:

```
milestones = [{"milestone_description":"descrip", "deposit_amount":1,
"due_date":"03-15-2015"},{"milestone_description":"descrip2",
"deposit_amount":5, "due_date":"03-20-2015"}]
```

Output:

```
HTTP400BadRequestError: HTTP Error 400: Code 1: FP2 offers should have at least one milestone defined.
```

Comment: Welcome @jer, could you edit your question and add the error you are getting ? :)

Answer (score 0):

your parameter is actually correct, unfortunately, current version of python-odesk library has an issue - oDesk API Team is aware of the problem, and we are going to fix this in upcoming update

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is there a stopgap solution / patch for a product that needs to use the api this week?

Comment: we will release a new version of the library in next few days, as usually in github and pipy - hence, in case you installed it as a package, you will need to upgrade it accordingly